# Cancel button not working in sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

when i am clicking on cancel button in sweetalert.js it still running the AJAX call i want to terminate the process on cancel button.

```
 swal({
        title: " Asking price for "+askData[0]+"?",
        text: "If you are sure press OK or edit this text",
        type: "input",
        inputType: "text",
        inputValue: "Hello "+askData[1]+", I am interested in buying your "+askData[0]+" of Variety :"+askData[3]+". Please update the Price!",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnCancelButton:true, 
        closeOnConfirm: false,
          showLoaderOnConfirm: true
       }, function(inputValue) {

        if (inputValue === "") {
            swal.showInputError("Please write something !");
            return false;
        }
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlEnq,
                       type: "GET"
                            });
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'saveUserMessage',
                    type: "POST",

                   data: {fieldUserId:fieldUserId,filedUserCompanyId:filedUserCompanyId,message:inputValue},
                    success: function(data)
                  {
                       swal("Done!", "Your message has been successfully sent.", "success");
                }
                })


                .error(function(data) {
                        swal.showInputError("Please write something !");
                    });

    });
});
});
```

Comment: it tried your code works fine. can u give some more info like errors etc..